# Is there a way to use a php server as a database?

Tags: python, replit

I am attempting to make a small mafia style game, and I am using replit. Would there be a way to use a php server (or an html server) as a database that I can connect to from a python project?

Comment: I suppose, if you *write* a database in PHP, sure?

Answer (score 1):

HTML nor PHP are databases. The "LAMP" stack uses PHP with **MySQL / MariaDB** for its database, which might be what you're referring to... However, the "P" there could also be Python `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

What you need in Python is a [Data Persistence layer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/persistence.html), which could just be a simple CSV / JSON file; however `pickle` module is easier to work with native Python types.

`sqlite` module can be used if you want the data to be more portable to other frameworks/languages.

And the final option is to actually run your own database server externally and expose it over a remote TCP / HTTP API connection (I don't think Repl.it supports running Docker containers).

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the actual machine, you can run something like [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/index.html) on the machine. You are running dangerously close to needing more security and what not though.

Security is important, but if you just want to "play around" running something like SQLite should answer your initial pass.

Comment: Could you run me through on how to do that?

Comment: @ColinWooldridge https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: I'd start [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pd-0G0MigUA) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=byHcYRpMgI4)